# PHP Laravel signature Client error: POST https://api.opentok.com/session/create resulted in a 403 Forbidden

Tags: opentok, tokbox

I am using "opentok/opentok": "^4.7" in PHP laravel project.

```
use OpenTok\OpenTok;

$apiKey = env('OPENTOK_API_KEY');
$apiSecret = env('OPENTOK_API_SECRET');

$apiObj = new OpenTok($apiKey, $apiSecret);
$session = $apiObj->createSession();
```

But it is giving me below error : "Invalid signature" , see screenshots attached.

1. I also tried https://tokbox.com/tools/credential-validator/  to validate signature , and the signatures are validated on this link.
2. I also tried https://tokbox.com/developer/tools/playground/  to check if session work, its working.
3. I checked this https://support.tokbox.com/hc/en-us/articles/360054612532-Unable-to-create-session-even-though-API-key-and-secret-are-valid  also,

and update time by hit command  : "sudo ntpdate time.nist.gov"

4. I also tried https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-PHP-SDK#creating-sessions  the hello world SDK, but giving same error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Hs4R.png)

Comment: Any chance you tried using the API directly, without the sdk wrapper? This would indicate to me that it's more than credentials, but something else blocking the API from being accessed, like a network firewall.

Comment: yes while using the api directly using curl, same issue.